# Bootstrap 4 Grid Row - Images Not Aligning Vertically

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a row of images that for some reason aren't aligning vertically.  If I use all the same images, it looks fine, but if I replace with a different image with slightly different dimensions it doesn't work.  Here's an example below:

[image]

Here's my HTML code..note I am using some custom CSS for an overlay, not sure if that could be causing a problem

```
<div className="container">

          <div className="row">

            <div className="col-xl-12 mx-auto mb-3">
              <h2 className="abouthead">Portfolio</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">
              <div
                className="view overlay hm-black-strong"
                data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#modal1"
              >
                <img
                  src="http://localhost:3002/images/dealmazing.JPG"
                  className="img-fluid"
                  alt="sample"
                />
                <div className="p-2 bg-info text-white">Deals Website</div>
                <div className="mask flex-center">
                  <p className="white-text">View Project</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">
              <div
                className="view overlay hm-black-strong"
                data-toggle="modal"
                data-target="#modal2"
              >
                <img
                  src="http://localhost:3002/images/crypto-portal.JPG"
                  className="img-fluid"
                  alt="sample"
                />
                <div className="p-2 bg-info text-white">
                  Cryptocurrency Portal
                </div>
                <div className="mask flex-center">
                  <p className="white-text">View Project</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">
              <div className="view overlay hm-black-strong">
                <img
                  src="http://localhost:3002/images/dealmazing.JPG"
                  className="img-fluid"
                  alt="sample"
                />
                <div className="p-2 bg-info text-white">Deals Website</div>
                <div className="mask flex-center">
                  <p className="white-text">View Project</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            </div>
```

//CSS

```
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.4.3/css/mdb.min.css);

.hm-gradient {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #f3e7e9 0%, #e3eeff 99%, #e3eeff 100%);
}
.darken-grey-text {
    color: #2E2E2E;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried specifying a height for your image? And then apply [Object-Fit CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property.

```
img {
  object-fit: cover;  
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;  
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, wasn't familiar with object-fit property so thanks for letting me know about that.